# Should we ban the author if there's spam/rude flags on his posts?

Tags: discussion, flags, banning

From [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work):

- 3 flags on a question (spam or offensive): question is banished from the front page and all question lists except search results.
- 6 flags (spam or offensive): post is [locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post), deleted, and the first revision owner loses 100 reputation.
- 1 flag from a moderator has the same effect as 6 flags from normal users: instant destruction.
- Contents of an answer that was deleted, and got at least one valid spam or offensive flag, [will be hidden](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199969/).
- Because a question with 6 flags is locked and deleted by the Community user, a 10k reputation user cannot undelete it.
- Each flag carries an implicit downvote for calculating the post's score *(it does not affect the caster's reputation)*.

I want to know why we don't ban the author's IP or account? For example ban the user for 1 day if 3 flags on a post, ban the user for 3 days if 6 flags on a post?

Don't we need that or we're already have that feature now?

---

**Why I am thinking that the author of spam/rude posts should be banned:**

1. I saw someone who posted **spam** posts actually is a spamming bot, it should be banned quickly like his post should be deleted quickly.
2. I saw someone who posted **rude** posts think our site is very bad. Then they should gone, leave this site, instead of spamming and abuse us.

Comment: Accounts which consistently break the rules *are* typically suspended/banned - though I believe this is a manual actual by the mods.

Comment: @Rob: That's what I thought. So I think we don't need mods do this. We can do this use flags.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This does happen, although it isn't necessarily triggered by a *single* deletion; still, somewhere between 1 and *n* spam- or offensive-deleted posts will throttle and then block further posts from the network on which they originated for a period of time.

This operates network-wide, so the most troublesome spammers - those that hit multiple sites repeatedly in a short period of time - are heavily restricted, with more leeway given to accounts which can be adequately handled via normal moderation tools.

Comment: That's good, how does this work? Our system will check the flags on user's posts cross-sites? And why do we give the spammers more leeway if they're not cross-sites?

Comment: Essentially, every network has a "spam score" associated with it, which gets incremented when a post is flagged - if the score is high enough, that network is blocked from posting. It's not so much that single-site spammers are given more leeway; rather, there are *other* restrictions in place to prevent folks from posting too quickly on a single site. You can get yourself banned by posting just on SO, but it'll take you longer because you have to wait between posts.