# Voting away snarkiness

Tags: discussion, voting, etiquette

Everyone knows how perceived snarkiness has been a thing for a while. [Joel's recent blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/03/28/the-next-ceo-of-stack-overflow/?cb=1) mentioned it again:

> an even bigger problem is rudeness, snark, or condescension that newcomers often see.

So why can't there be a voting button for attitude that directly affects SO rep, in addition to the "correctness" vote that currently exists? People who are courteous and polite ought to get points--even more points if they're also correct.

Why not let the "free market" fight negative attitudes? It seems obvious that the content on SO exists in its current state because people were willing to have traded a certain amount of time for a certain amount of SO rep. Therefore, snarky comments and answers exist when bad attitude doesn't factor much into that equation. So if snarkiness is a problem then it's too inexpensive to be snarky (just like sending spam emails is inexpensive), and a snarky correct answer gets upvoted approximately as much as a polite correct answer. Why not change the market equation?

Comment: There are already ways to handle this issue, we are not in the business of judging attitudes / people. It seems like a shift towards social media platforms.

Comment: Detecting _"snarkiness"_ is a completely grey zone, and may heavily depend on cultural views. I'd not link such mechanism automated, but still be judged by real human moderators.

Comment: "snarky" answers should be *fixed*, not left to rot.

Comment: It wouldn’t work. The contributions *you* perceive as snarky would get upvoted by others who don’t perceive them that way at all. Do remember that the vote buttons don’t *just* mean technical correctness. They’re a total quality score, a combination of correctness, usefulness, and helpfulness. If the post has such an attitude problem that it becomes less useful or less helpful, then you already can and should downvote it. If it’s unrecoverably rude, then flag it for removal.

Comment: @KevinB Yet we leave incorrect answers to rot, do we not?

Comment: @MattThomas Yes, because we aren't expected to fix inaccuracies in answers to make them correct. We are however obligated to improve them in other ways, such as correcting grammar/readability, removing fluff, etc.. (Obligated might not be the right word there, but... meh, it works)

Comment: It's easy to do this. Just allow downvotes on comments.

Comment: @MattThomas "We do it with X" isn't a reason to let Y happen, if Y and X are both bad. Ideally, we should stop to do X as well...

Comment: Mob rule.  That seems...less than wise.  Considering new users outnumber curators by at least an order of magnitude or two, it wouldn't take long for the, "free market" to incentivize going with the mob.  And now we wouldn't be voting away snarkiness; we'd be actively supporting straight up hostility.

Comment: @TravisJ does the current system not work fine? Down-voting of comments might open up another avenue of abuse which mods would have to monitor / handle, plus, I'm of the opinion that the turnover time for flag handling is astoundingly good considering the size of the site.

Comment: @TravisJ You mean "inconsequential rep-wise" downvotes on comments? Cause if downvotes like that cost rep, upvotes on comments have to give rep, and that feels like an **awful** thing to get started on Stack :/

Comment: @Patrice though not necessarily, up-vote on an answer doesn't give anything but on down-vote you lose rep.

Comment: @Script47 for the receiver of the vote.... they both influence rep. From the voter's perspective, it's different, right.

Comment: @Patrice - Not from a rep standpoint. 99.999% of snark is in comments.

Comment: @TravisJ I agree, and having downvotes there would definitely help kill snark. Or at least show what the community is able to callout as "real" snark. I just wasn't sure if your comment meant it influences rep or not ^^

Comment: @fbueckert I see it as distinct from mob rule... more like "tuned" mob rule aka distributed policing that has been specifically incentivized. It's not like we'd be giving the mob a "vote for what feature to put in the SO site next" button that automatically implements whatever they ask for

Comment: Nope. You'd just be allowing anyone and everyone to judge what anyone else says, correctness forgotten. We'd be Reddit, all over again. Why, again, do we want to allow popularity to take over? For...anything?

Comment: @fbueckert I think there's a double standard in that question: "popularity" (of a kind) already controls the content on SO... the answer with the most votes wins. I think we view that kind of popular control as being okay because it's the most popularly _correct_ content. And being correct is part of the purpose of SO. But the outgoing CEO is saying that politeness and attitude is _also_ part of the purpose of SO; he said it's "a big challenge for Stack Overflow". So mixing in the concept of the most popularly _polite_ content fits, too, does it not?

Comment: Popularity is generally a problem that we have to fight *against*.  For instance, many types of questions are popular, but don't make for good questions.  Resource recommendations, for example; people *always* want us to tell them what books they should get to learn something. Used to be a very popular type of question.  But it's still off-topic.  Votes should denote quality, as best we can.  If someone is being snarky or rude, don't allow more people to vote on it; that just exposes it to more people!  Just flag it so it goes away.

Comment: @fbueckert I understand the point about popularity in general. But I believe that politeness votes are just as distinct from Reddit popularity as correctness votes are. People wouldn't be voting on if they like the content or not, neither would they be voting on how much they want the content. Instead, it would be specifically a politeness vote, similar to the specifically correctness vote that currently exists.

Comment: @Script47 - How would downvoting a comment open up an avenue of abuse?

Comment: @Script47 re: your first comment "there are already ways to handle this issue". It seems evident that Joel judges the current system to be inadequate. Otherwise, would he repeatedly say there's a "big problem"? _Something_ needs to change, does it not?

Comment: And, again, you're subjecting all content to mob rule.  Now answerers not only have to convey technical information, but they have to do it in a more political correct way, or suffer the consequences.  That's if everyone is honest about their, "politeness" vote and everything works correctly.  Honestly, do you expect people to conform to that?  Look at all the scandals that have swept the US lately.  People get passionate.  What was no big deal yesterday must be condemned today, and now you're subjecting someone to flak for no good reason at all.

Comment: You know it's going to be used to retaliate against something else the user has done, and that goes totally against the voting model; vote on the *post*.  Not the user.  Never on the user.  If a post has content you feel is problematic, flag it, or edit it if you feel you can do so.  There's no need to add yet another barrier to just posting content.

Comment: Also, let's think for a minute how much difficulty people have with 'Low Quality Answer' as a flag, or 'NAA'. Or even, has we have often seen on meta, no one seems to be able to agree about what should merit a 'rude' flag. That means the community isn't even aligned with itself as to what it rude. I personally think old users won't care about *that* counter, but new users will use it to have 'revenge' on others. Also.... Downvotes unlock at 125 rep... You intend the same for your 'politeness' vote?

Comment: For some perspective on the idea that different people have a different opinion on what polite means, if your feature existed, I'm willing to bet this meta question here would have a ton of "impolite" votes.  Just something to consider.

Comment: The problem seems to be that people already interpret very basic requests as "snark" and "rude". For example the usual "welcome to so, ..." spiel already offends some people. Without people reminding newcomers how to properly ask question we wouldn't get anything done and just answer out of the blue, for what we think is the question. It'll help noone.

Comment: +1 for Matt. 100% agree with it, despite the -29. Stay strong. The people that spend their first 5 minutes here will decide if they want to spend the next decade here. You don’t need to be a genius to figure that out. Tech guys by nature are not the most personable. So, what’s wrong with going above and beyond on the nice scale. You don’t need a downvote for being mean, just a +1 for being personable. It worked for Pavlov and the tuning fork. It’s classical conditioning 101.

Comment: @Jesse `despite the -29. Stay strong` Why does he need to stay strong? Where is the damage that OP took? For getting downvoted in MSO? It's a typical misinterpretation of voting system. **Downvoting is NOT and NEVER BEEN a sign of the so called rudeness, snark, or condescension.** It is plainly (at here in MSO) a simple, straightforward and anonymous way to present members' disagreement to OP's opinion. People need to grow up and understand disagreement doesn't equals to being rude.

Comment: @MattThomas I am just pointing out a typical example how people can misinterpreted how the system work. Everyone may have their own standard for the so called rudeness, snark, or condescension. Partrice find my usable to bold and cap bit too strong, I have different opinion and I believe I am not alone. Good news is that we are still in a range of agree to disagree range. However we do know there are people simply take downvote/clarification comment/closure offensive, and we are not short of such examples everyday.

Comment: Cont. And this is the main reason I feel butt hurt when SE employees post these kind of typical *welcome-ish* articles. It's good for PR, but very, very bad for the community. It simply provide more bullet for those who post gimme teh codz but get closed, those who post non-understandable questions but get downvoted, those get banned for repeatedly low quality posts, etc to shoot at good contributors in the community.

Comment: @Patrice I failed to communicate playfulness. I think I'm just another example of how difficult it is to successfully communicate. Rereading my comment in light of what you said I can see your point about ruffling feathers. Deleted.

Comment: @tweray I'll give it another go. <playfulness>But I feel hurt and need to be affirmed!</playfulness> == <seriousness>It does feel good knowing I'm not alone. But I'm totally fine with everyone disagreeing with me and am not upset with anyone and don't feel as though I've taken damage. In fact, this whole thing has been pretty enlightening and there have been some good ideas tossed around, so I think I've profited.</seriousness>

Answer (score 14):

**Fearing people into submission until they exhibit the desired behaviour is a crueller endeavour than the snark we are trying to get rid of.**

There is a behaviour, snarkiness, that you want to address through the removal of reputation. This is akin to a common training pattern that has been used with animals for millennia. Here, the removal of reputation is the stick hit that is applied until the desired behaviour is being seen.

I completely, utterly and with every breath of my body disagree with this way of interacting with people.

**Perceived snarkiness**

> Everyone knows how perceived snarkiness has been a thing for a while. Joel's recent blog post mentioned it again:

Some people have been very vocal about it and there seem to be a possibly sizeable population of humans that perceive Stack Overflow as generally snarky.

Orthogonally, a lot of these vocal people have very, very rarely shown a behaviour that was not snarky, aggressive or simply violent towards humans that don't understand things as they do.

> So why can't there be a voting button for attitude that directly affects SO rep, in addition to the "correctness" vote that currently exists? People who are courteous and polite ought to get points--even more points if they're also correct.

That is a quite popular and saddeningly superficial opinion, insofar as superficial means "superficially eloquent about a deeper way of thinking of a human being". Being polite, or courteous, is only loosely correlated to the real appreciation, or respect if you will, of a human towards another human.

**I think everyone will be better off if we try and find ways to value actual respect and appreciation rather than external behaviours of respect and appreciation.**

The problem is much deeper than how we interact with each other. Merely trying to change the symptom, might not change how we perceive each other.  But trying to vote on how we perceive other humans attitude is the slipping ground of slipping grounds.

**Snarkiness should be flagged, removed, destroyed, because it drifts away from the actual goal, and because that much we can do with at least a bit of objectivity.**

---

I would like to cite an [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372568/576767) of mine about a somewhat related subject:

> Being welcoming, does not mean adding please and thanks everywhere.

Tone is a super subjective thing. Some people seem to think that "Apologies, but your code is completely undecipherable" would be better than without the apology. If really, one detects snark from a message based on the presence of some keywords, and not on the actual **content** of the message, we, as humanity, have a much deeper problem than snarkiness on Stack Overflow.

**The envelope, is not the message, and I fear many users of this site are trying to focus on the envelope when the content is what actually matters.**

Answer (score 9):

In complex systems, even small changes can lead to huge and unexpected results - there must be really compelling advantages to take such risks.

My concerns about such change are:

1. I doubt it will pan out as you expect. Most of the snark doesn't come out of the blue: It hits mostly questions of low quality - after appearing in the "active tab" for a short time, those questions will virtually disappear and not attract  many visitors via google - the lion's share of visitors will be the curators, who are frustrated with SO being misused as personal help-desk/free debugging service. My prediction is, that they will be inclined to up-vote "Learn how to use the debugger"-answers rather than down-vote them. I know, I would. Partly because I genuinely think it is the most helpful (in the long run) answer one can give to a debugging-request and partly out of resistance.
2. It would add additional routes to game the system (as if we don't have enough already): if ration upvote/downvote rate is the same for the usefulness-vote, then writing "Read the docs"-answers will be the easiest strategy to earn reputation: just one out of five must agree with you and you win.
3. Is snark in answers really an issue? I assume not that many would take their time to answer question and then spend some more time to add snark to it. I don't have the numbers, but would be really surprised if comments are responsible for less than 90% of the snark. So taking risks of creating more snark-answers (see my two points above) is just too high for possible gains.
4. This would be a much more lenient system than we have in place now: Snark is not tolerated and after some violations, one loses all of his reputation and privileges. Compared to these "draconian" measures, your proposal is to pay some small amount of reputation. Thus snark becomes a privilege - get some thousands of reputation and have so much snark as you like.

---

However, your point, that the current ways of dealing with snark don't work, is probably right.

One could argue, that snarks aren't the disease but just a symptom - the disease is the low quality of the incoming questions.

People coming to SO for help don't understand, that this is not a help-desk but an effort to build a high quality Q&A for programmers and the asker has a responsibility to do research before wasting everybody's time with typos in code. Curators don't come to SO and think: "I had a bad day at the office, let's find some innocent souls and snark at them.", but we are all just human, get frustrated and sometimes type rather than walk away.

Probably, as long as there are a lot of low-quality questions and we are still humans with emotions, there will be snarkiness in one form or another and SO will be perceived as not welcoming: First for snark in comments, then for down-votes without comments, then for seen no reaction/feedback at all after asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

> So why can't there be a voting button for attitude that directly affects SO rep, in addition to the "correctness" vote that currently exists? People who are courteous and polite ought to get points--even more points if they're also correct.

Currently at the bottom of the **comments** to your question is a link-button (looks like a link, works like a button) that says: "show **18** more comments". This is created due to having a number of comments with differing upvotes. While there is no downvoting of the comments the ones with the fewest votes are hidden.

It's an approach to accentuate the positive, and allow comments that are not flaggable to remain unscathed; save for any replies.

For **answers** we do have up and down voting, with downvoting of answers coming at a cost to the voter while downvoting of **questions** is free.

Rather than 'voting for/against attitude' (or the perception of such) we have flagging. See: **[Should we ban the author if there's spam/rude flags on his posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311856/should-we-ban-the-author-if-theres-spam-rude-flags-on-his-posts)** and note that if the community agrees that someone is being rude then **6 flags will cost them 100 reputation** - perhaps that's more reputation lost than you would suggest that 6 'downvotes for attitude' ought to cost.

Abusiveness when flagged can also result in a suspension, quite often for a week with repeat offenders getting a month or more.

> ... Therefore, snarky comments and answers exist when bad attitude doesn't factor much into that equation. So if snarkiness is a problem then it's too inexpensive to be snarky (just like sending spam emails is inexpensive), and a snarky correct answer gets upvoted approximately as much as a polite correct answer. Why not change the market equation?

A loss of 100 reputation and suspension, banning, or account deletion isn't a small penalty.

There are no statistics attached to your question showing that snarky answers earn as much reputation as a polite, positive, and supportive tone.

Theoretically the best questions and answers get the most upvotes, but we don't influence others votes and people are free to vote up or down regardless of what is written, otherwise we'd have exponential voting instead of one for one.

It's true that the voting system isn't perfect but that's the nature of voting. Does voting on each nuance of a post rather than a single vote or flag for the overall quality offer a more refined quality assessment of what ought to rise to the top and what should fall, you have available a few means to judge this already: views, comments, answers, flags and votes - needing more aspects to vote on is catamount to voting on the candidate's hairstyle.

Upvotes earn more and downvotes cost less, even a downvote on an answer is half the cost to the voter than the poster. Flags cost the most, where enough of them trigger automated actions and intervention from the Moderators.

Altering the manner in which votes and reputation is accumulated without some examples and statistics to support your position places a dividing line between how reputation used to be earned and how you propose it ought to be earned moving forward, without any support as to the benefits of skewing past and future earnings.

Comment: +1 for "places a dividing line ... without any support". This teaches me a bit more about how things get done on SO as well as how others are perceiving all this. Thanks!

Answer (score -22):

It might be a good idea. The perception of attitude might be improved similar to how the quality of answers is encouraged with the existing voting system.

But there's been a ton of noise in people's responses that needs to be dealt with, so...

## These are not reasons why it's a bad idea:

#### It treats people like animals, akin to beating them with sticks

This is no more true of a politeness voting button than it is of the correctness voting button. It's just highlighting a shared aspect, but in a negative way.

For example, one can just as easily say "There is a quality, incorrectness, that you want to address through removal of reputation. This is akin to a common negative training pattern". Yet we value the correctness vote.

#### What we already have works. You can edit, flag, etc...

What we have does not work according to management. And according to whoever all these sensitive people are who are complaining of how mean people are on SO. If management thought it worked then Joel wouldn't say "it's a big problem" on multiple occasions. And if sensitive people didn't think it was a problem then there wouldn't be anything to talk about.

#### Actual respect and appreciation are what we need, not just the appearance

Right. But the *perception* of attitude is what we're talking about.

#### It's impossible to formalize and depends heavily on culture. It's subjective

That's why you empower the mob. The mob is quite capable of detecting this. Give them a voting button and you've created a machine which detects *precisely 100% of the time* the exact same perception of poor attitude that is the problem. Because the mob is the one complaining, meaning it's the one detecting, meaning it's the one capable of correcting.

#### It won't work because while you downvote something based on your perception, someone else will upvote it

The perception of anything is *by definition* subjective. Therefore this is no more a problem for the voting solution than for any possible solution. Therefore this is not an enlightening objection because it doesn't distinguish between any solutions.

#### You can already downvote

Not for attitude. The downvote button says "This answer is not useful" for answers, which is about utility and correctness, not attitude. It says "This question does not show any research effort" for questions, which is also about utility. And there is no downvote for comments.

#### It's mob rule

Like how 25% of all viewers of this question downvoted because they don't like it?

Besides, it is precisely the mob who have created the problem of a perception of poor attitude. The mob is the one who knows how the mob is perceiving things. So give them a button and the problem will go away.

#### We'd be like Reddit--the most popular content would win

No, the most polite and correct content would win. Because people would be voting on politeness and correctness.

#### People won't use the politeness vote correctly

People also don't use the correctness vote correctly. This doesn't make the correctness vote wrong or bad.

#### It makes more work for answerers

Unless you can write a program which automatically improves tone of voice, then I think this will be a difficulty shared by all solutions to the problem.

Comment: "The perception of poor attitude will be reduced." There is absolutely no indication whatsoever that this is the case. What you propose, for people to be able to downvote, with effect on reputation, what they feel is poor attitude, is completely uncharted territory. It's interesting, and quite invalid, that you present this as some kind of certitude... And yes, there is definitely a difference between "that is poor attitude" and "that is a poor technical *answer*". One of those is objectively quantifiable, to some degree. The other is complete wind.

Comment: For instance... I think you exhibit poor attitude, in how you posted that answer. Does that make it so? You did not care to expand on the points you address, and mostly say "I disagree", without supporting argument or reflexion. How is that constructive? Should my impression of your behaviour really impact your reputation (and, more reliably, moderation ability) on SO?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Thank you for the feedback. I'm editing to improve my answer

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Regarding the addressed points, I was trying to be terse (there are a lot of them) so I can expand. But I'll need some help seeing where additional argumentation is needed

Comment: These are valuable edits, I think they do improve this answer.

Comment: *"No, the most polite and correct content would win. Because people would be voting on politeness and correctness."* Right, like how people using the current buttons are voting on usefulness/quality. /s

Comment: @KevinB Do you mean that people are currently using the voting buttons to express an element of their perception of attitude? If so, then my idea isn't original: the current system already encapsulates it. And if the current system is broken, then so is my idea. Or do you mean more broadly that regardless of what the hover text is on a button, if it's the only button then they're going to press it? If so, then that could be justification for adding another button so that the current voting buttons aren't a catch-all.

Comment: My point is people abuse the current voting tools. They use them for reasons they aren't actually intended for. They reach for it when a close reason might be a better fit for example, or when the post has poor grammar that anyone can fix, etc.

Comment: And with that in mind, you could expect a new voting mechanism to be abused in the same way, people upvoting a snarky response twice because they find it funny, or using both upvote types because the user helped them, rather than because it wasn't snarky, etc.. It basically just doubles the effect of existing upvotes because pretty much everyone who uses one will use the other.

Answer (score -23):

This is a reasonable question and is a great recommendation related to classical conditioning and improving StackOverflow (likely to be downvoted, but eh, it’s fine)

> clas·si·cal con·di·tion·ing
>   nounPSYCHOLOGY
>       1   a learning process that occurs when two stimuli are repeatedly paired: a response which is at first elicited by the second stimulus is eventually elicited by the first stimulus alone.

Reference 1:
http://www.rnl.caltech.edu/publications/pdf/old/AER_forthcoming_Pavlovian.pdf

In this experiment:

> Every participant performed three tasks: (1) a liking-rating task, (2) a familiarity-rating task, and (3) a bidding task.

StackOverflow already does 2 of those 3. Why not do the third one?

Reference 2:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3465491/

> In the field of artificial intelligence and machine learning, reinforcement learning algorithms with different computational demands are often used in tandem [7]. Specifically, algorithms that are broadly classified as “model-free” have low computational requirements and have been used in parallel with more computationally intensive “model-based” algorithms. Derived in part from learning rules in experimental psychology [8], model-free algorithms such as temporal difference learning state that learning only occurs when the experienced value or current expectation of a particular motivational outcome deviates from that previously expected based upon environmental stimuli.

There is economic value to StackOverflow being nice, and niceness can be more self-regulating if it is incentivized. If a judge [or admin] determines you are nice, it’s not the same as whether your peers think you are nice.

I think the leadership of StackOverflow feels that people do need to be nicer; otherwise, they wouldn’t write things like this:
https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Also, it’s got to be really subjective to police this code of conduct:
https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Yes, being nice and getting points by itself does seem somewhat like a participation trophy, but when complimented with other characteristics it makes sense. Many people are here to get points and answer questions. Some people are here to find jobs. Others, like me, are here as a hobbyist. If points didn’t work, then we wouldn’t have a points system at all would we?

Great job Matt. It makes a lot of sense to me.

Comment: *"it’s got to be really hard to police this code of conduct"* It isn't hard at all. It takes me merely a few seconds to handle flags on comments. Can you explain how Stack Overflow does *any* of the tasks you cite from that article?

Comment: Interestingly, you seem to support my point about trying to condition people through adversarial stimuli.

Comment: Yeah, that’s all I got. Debating with lions isn’t my thing. Enjoy.

Comment: Roar? Where are the lions?

Comment: @CodyGray Not here yet, but Matt lost and I’m losing fast. I’m on my way out of the den now. Running for hills and watching the ticker go down. Lol.

Comment: Seriously, I have no idea what you're talking about. Are you watching *The Lion King* on a second screen? How has anyone "lost" here? I'm very confused.

Comment: @Jesse I'll race you to the bottom! :)

Comment: @Cody it's an analogy for the 'meta crew'. Jesse doesn't seem to be a fan of the reception they'll get here, and puts that akin to jumping in a pit of Lions. It's a shame, cause whatever merit his position may have is eclipsed by that lack of good faith in others, Imho. We've gotten to a point where both sides of the debate quit the debate before it even starts.... It's a shame. That has ground the community to a standstill I'd say.

Comment: @Patrice well said.

Comment: @Jesse ironic that you call it well said, when you are backing out of the conversation. My point is you *shouldn't* be doing this..... anyway. And in a place where you know downvoting means disagreement, why do you see this as hostile? Do you think that we aren't allowed to disagree with you? Cause that's the vibe that "suggestions shouldn't be downvoted" gives, when I know I vote up and down on these things based on if I agree with them or not. I know it's not easy to "stand up" and be told people disagree, but the only "aggressivity" I see here is how quickly *you* go to push others away :/

Comment: Ugh, I’ll be closing my account today. It’s sad that we get 30 downvotes in an hour here, but our questions go days unanswered with no votes. Thanks for the time we had together. Enjoy.

Comment: @Jesse sad that this is the result here. Notice that you're leaving for perceived rudeness/attack, or something like that. When in fact all people are doing is saying "we don't agree with you". Seriously, look at the thread, all you see is people trying to discuss your ideas, and someone (me, I guess) that is just sad that you don't want to engage further, as I truly believe that your ideas have value (regardless of if I agree with them or not). Hopefully you'll reconsider. We need people on both sides of the issue, or else we'll just become an echo chamber and nothing will ever evolve...

Comment: Also, for the pedantic minded... you're getting about a downvote an hour... your answer stands at -12, in 11 hours. Don't let your emotions cloud what you see and make this worse than it is....